# anchor does not work inside of div, but it work on top of div

Tags: html, css

anchor does not work, but if a move the anchor to the top it works. I don't understand whats going on. this is my first time asking a question in StackOverflow. thanks in advanced.here is the full html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Salvador Portfolio</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" >


</head>

<body>
<!--this is for the introduction in portfolio-->
<section>
     <div class="section_text">
    <h1>Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
      </div>
</section>
<!--aside where my info and some nav links-->
        <div class="aside">

         <img src="my_self.jpg" class="image_myself" alt="my self" width="100" height="100">
          <a href="www.google.com" class="anchor_Send_Email">Send me an email</a>   
         <form></form>

            <h3>Hello! My name is Salvador 
            Sandoval, I'm a programmer on this website I will show you projects a did   in college, also some of my personal projects and programming concepts I learn in college. visiting.</h3>



        </div>  
<!--this is where all show explanation & code -->
  <div class="content">


        <h3>7 reasons why trainers like our books</h3>
            <h2>Modular book organization</h2>
            <p>In the first section or two of all our books, we present the core content
            for the book, which includes a complete subset of usable skills. After the core
            content, each section of the book is designed as an independent module. This
            means that these sections don't have to be taught in sequence. As a result, you
            can customize your courses by assigning just those sections that you want to
            teach.</p>
            <p>Whenever possible, each of the chapters is also designed as an independent
            module. When this is true, you can assign just those chapters that are right
            for your courses. This approach also makes the chapters better for on-the-job
            reference later on.</p>

            <h2>Top-down chapter design</h2>
            <p>Unlike many competing books and products, most chapters in our books have a
            unique top-down design that moves from the simple to complex. This makes it
            easier for trainees to learn. It also means that you can present the topics at
            the start of a chapter to make sure everyone understands the essential details,
            without presenting all of the topics in a chapter. Then, your trainees can
            learn the other topics on their own or as they're needed on the job.</p>

            <h2>Paired-pages format</h2>
            <p>If you page through one of our books, you'll see that all of the information
            is presented in &quot;paired pages.&quot; In each pair, the right page is a
            figure that contains the syntax, guidelines, and examples, and the left page is
            text that contains the perspective and extra explanation.</p>
            <p>One benefit of this format is that it lets trainees learn at their own pace.
            If, for example, you're a novice, you'll probably want to read the text on the
            left as you refer to the figure on the right. But if you have experience, you
            may be able to get all the information you need from the figure. Either way,
            our customers tell us that they love this presentation method because it helps
            them learn faster and better.</p>

            <h2>Performance on the job</h2>
            <p>On-the-job performance is the measure of a successful course. And our
            paired-pages format makes it easy for your trainees to access all the
            information you've covered long after the course is over. </p>
            <p>Instead of having to dig through the text or handouts, they can use the
            expanded table of contents or the index to find the topic they're looking for.
            Then, the figure on the righthand page will give them the details they need to
            apply what they learned in your course.</p>
            <p>This type of quick reference is absolutely essential when you're working
            with the hundreds of classes, methods, and properties of an OO language like
            Java, Visual Basic, or C#...and yet no other books offer this unique format.</p>

            <h2>More practice in less time</h2>
            <p>The exercises for our books give trainees a chance to get valuable, hands-on
            experience without wasting any time. That's because we provide the starting
            code, either from our web site or the Instructor's CD, so that trainees don't
            have to enter routine code that they already know.</p>
            <p>Sometimes, these exercises guide the trainees through the application of
            what they've just learned. Sometimes, they challenge the trainees to apply what
            they've learned in new ways. And you can assign the exercises so your trainees
            do them in class or on their own.</p>
            <p>Incidentally, unlike other books, <i>our exercises never present new skills
            or information</i>. As we see it, this is the only sensible approach to text
            and exercise design. Curiously, though, the exercises in some books do present
            new skills. Unfortunately, this means that (1) trainees who don't do the
            exercises don't learn the new skills, and (2) there's no easy way for trainees
            to find the information they need if they're having trouble since the skills
            haven't been covered yet.</p>

            <h2>Complete, real-world applications</h2>
            <p>From the first book we published in 1974 to the present, all of our books
            teach by presenting complete, real-world applications that include design,
            code, and all related components. These applications help your trainees get
            started quickly and also help them reach new skill levels. As we see it,
            studying applications like these is the best way to learn how all of the parts
            of an application work together, so this is an essential part of the learning
            process.</p>

            <h2>Complete instructor's materials</h2>
            <p>If you review the instructor's materials that come with the Instructor's CD
            for one of our books, you'll see that our CDs provide everything else you need
            for an effective course...except the busywork. That's why you should be able to
            plan and implement a course that's based on one of our books in record time.
            Once that's done, our books and instructional materials will help ensure the
            success of your course.</p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the full css

```
  section{
   height: 100vh;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background-color:#f794f2;
}

.section_text {
  color:#f7eb94;
  font-size:15vh;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.aside {

    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    /*relative to it would move to the side*/
    position:relative;
    /* background-color:#5bde47; */

}

.image_myself{
    margin-left: 25%;

}
.anchor_Send_Email{
margin-left: 25%;

}
.content{
    display:inline;
    /*relative so it would move to the left*/
    position:relative;

}
```

--------here is where I have the trouble

```
<div class="aside">
            <!--if a move anchor here it works-->
         <img src="my_self.jpg" class="image_myself" alt="my self" width="100" height="100">
      <!--here it does not work-->
          <a href="#index" class="anchor_Send_Email">Send me an email</a>   
         <form></form>

            <h3>Hello! My name is Salvador 
            Sandoval, I'm a programmer on this website I will show you projects a did 
            in college, also some of my personal projects and programming concepts I 
            learn in college. visiting.</h3>



        </div>
```

This is the css the use this part of html

```
.aside {

    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    /*relative to it would move to the side*/
    position:relative;
    /* background-color:#5bde47; */

}

.image_myself{
    margin-left: 25%;

}
.anchor_Send_Email{
margin-left: 25%;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please specify what  "anchor does not work" means: The link doesn't show up? Or it shows up, but clicking on it doesn't do what you expect? Or some other thing?

Comment: This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

By using position relative on the content and sidebar you were overriding some of the features of float, so the content div was actually over the sidebar even though the contents looked to be positioned correctly. I just removed the `position: relative;` rules and it seems fine now. To see what was happening, right click and inspect the link in your code and you'll see .content is actually being selected.

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #f794f2;
}

.section_text {
  color: #f7eb94;
  font-size: 15vh;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.aside {
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
  /* background-color:#5bde47; */
}

.image_myself {
  margin-left: 25%;
  display: block;
}

.anchor_Send_Email {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.content {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Salvador Portfolio</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <!--this is for the introduction in portfolio-->
  <section>
    <div class="section_text">
      <h1>Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--aside where my info and some nav links-->
  <div class="aside">

    <img src="my_self.jpg" class="image_myself" alt="my self" width="100" height="100">

    <a href="www.google.com" class="anchor_Send_Email">Send me an email</a>

    <form></form>

    <h3>Hello! My name is Salvador Sandoval, I'm a programmer on this website I will show you projects a did in college, also some of my personal projects and programming concepts I learn in college. visiting.</h3>



  </div>
  <!--this is where all show explanation & code -->
  <div class="content">


    <h3>7 reasons why trainers like our books</h3>
    <h2>Modular book organization</h2>
    <p>In the first section or two of all our books, we present the core content for the book, which includes a complete subset of usable skills. After the core content, each section of the book is designed as an independent module. This means that these
      sections don't have to be taught in sequence. As a result, you can customize your courses by assigning just those sections that you want to teach.
    </p>
    <p>Whenever possible, each of the chapters is also designed as an independent module. When this is true, you can assign just those chapters that are right for your courses. This approach also makes the chapters better for on-the-job reference later on.</p>

    <h2>Top-down chapter design</h2>
    <p>Unlike many competing books and products, most chapters in our books have a unique top-down design that moves from the simple to complex. This makes it easier for trainees to learn. It also means that you can present the topics at the start of a chapter
      to make sure everyone understands the essential details, without presenting all of the topics in a chapter. Then, your trainees can learn the other topics on their own or as they're needed on the job.</p>

    <h2>Paired-pages format</h2>
    <p>If you page through one of our books, you'll see that all of the information is presented in &quot;paired pages.&quot; In each pair, the right page is a figure that contains the syntax, guidelines, and examples, and the left page is text that contains
      the perspective and extra explanation.</p>
    <p>One benefit of this format is that it lets trainees learn at their own pace. If, for example, you're a novice, you'll probably want to read the text on the left as you refer to the figure on the right. But if you have experience, you may be able to
      get all the information you need from the figure. Either way, our customers tell us that they love this presentation method because it helps them learn faster and better.</p>

    <h2>Performance on the job</h2>
    <p>On-the-job performance is the measure of a successful course. And our paired-pages format makes it easy for your trainees to access all the information you've covered long after the course is over. </p>
    <p>Instead of having to dig through the text or handouts, they can use the expanded table of contents or the index to find the topic they're looking for. Then, the figure on the righthand page will give them the details they need to apply what they learned
      in your course.</p>
    <p>This type of quick reference is absolutely essential when you're working with the hundreds of classes, methods, and properties of an OO language like Java, Visual Basic, or C#...and yet no other books offer this unique format.</p>

    <h2>More practice in less time</h2>
    <p>The exercises for our books give trainees a chance to get valuable, hands-on experience without wasting any time. That's because we provide the starting code, either from our web site or the Instructor's CD, so that trainees don't have to enter routine
      code that they already know.</p>
    <p>Sometimes, these exercises guide the trainees through the application of what they've just learned. Sometimes, they challenge the trainees to apply what they've learned in new ways. And you can assign the exercises so your trainees do them in class
      or on their own.</p>
    <p>Incidentally, unlike other books, <i>our exercises never present new skills
            or information</i>. As we see it, this is the only sensible approach to text and exercise design. Curiously, though, the exercises in some books do present new skills. Unfortunately, this means that (1) trainees who don't do the exercises
      don't learn the new skills, and (2) there's no easy way for trainees to find the information they need if they're having trouble since the skills haven't been covered yet.</p>

    <h2>Complete, real-world applications</h2>
    <p>From the first book we published in 1974 to the present, all of our books teach by presenting complete, real-world applications that include design, code, and all related components. These applications help your trainees get started quickly and also
      help them reach new skill levels. As we see it, studying applications like these is the best way to learn how all of the parts of an application work together, so this is an essential part of the learning process.
    </p>

    <h2>Complete instructor's materials</h2>
    <p>If you review the instructor's materials that come with the Instructor's CD for one of our books, you'll see that our CDs provide everything else you need for an effective course...except the busywork. That's why you should be able to plan and implement
      a course that's based on one of our books in record time. Once that's done, our books and instructional materials will help ensure the success of your course.</p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you JasonB this fix the problem. I really appreciate your help.